# Please explain objective of Flow Control Action Sampler in 5.0 version

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

objective of Flow Control Action Sampler in JMeter. what we can achieve with this Sampler during load test?

Answer (score 3):

**[Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action)** sampler is used along with the logical controllers to control the sampler execution.

1. To pause (sleep) current or all thread for specified amount of time (duration is set in milliseconds). You could use a JMeter variable or property to set a dynamic value

[image]

2. To stop the current or all threads after completing the execution of samples in progress
3. To stop the current or all threads immediately without waiting for samples in progress to complete. **Stop Now** option should be selected.
   [image]
4. To move to  the next iteration

Also you can use Flow Control Action sampler to introduce a Timer in between two samplers. Please see the [suggestion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) from official website. 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Sleep for specified amount of time (for example you can [implement pacing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-easily-implement-pacing-jmeter/) using Flow Control Action Sampler)
2. Start next iteration of the current loop (for example can be applied for [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller), [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller), [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller))
3. Start next iteration of the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
4. Gracefully or immediately stop current thread or all threads (the whole test)